# Exporting SCSS Variables to JS (auto looping variables)

Tags: javascript, sass

> **UPDATE**: If you plan to implement the `export` solution, you **must**
>   place it in a separate file to prevent redundant exports in your
>   compiled CSS code. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536228/export-sass-scss-variables-to-javascript-without-exporting-them-to-css).

I recently learned that you can export styles from SCSS into JS like so:

**_variables.scss**

```
:export {
    some-variable: 'some-value';
}
```

**app.js**

```
import styles from 'core-styles/brand/_variables.scss';
```

Based on this, my `_variables.scss` is formatted like so:

```
/* Define all colours */
$some-color:       #000;
$another-color:    #000;

// Export the color palette to make it accessible to JS
:export {
    some-color: $some-color;
    another-color: $another-color;
}
```

The issue with the above format is that I have to re-define each of my variables within `export`. Therefore, I am interested to know whether there is a way to `loop` though each of my variables automatically and export them to JS?

Comment: What kind of loader setup is required to be able to use `:export`? I'm struggling to find any documentation online.

Comment: @MaximoMussini - it is known as ICSS (Interoperable CSS), check this link out: https://glenmaddern.com/articles/interoperable-css. There are also various other articles online, just put interoperable CSS into Google :-D

Comment: At least with Vite/Rollup, it is necessary to name the file containing the `:export` rule `*.module.scss` rather than simply `*.scss`.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Some improvements to the accepted answer:

- Use [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) so you will be able to individually export a variable.
- Set the `@each` directive outside so it won't generate a new `:export` at-rule for each variable.

---

**_variables.scss**

```scss
$theme-colors: (
  'someColor': #000,
  'anotherColor': #FFF,
);

:export {
  @each $key, $value in $theme-colors {
    #{unquote($key)}: $value;
  }
}
```

**app.js**

```js
import styles from './core-styles/brand/_variables.scss' // { anotherColor: "#FFF", someColor: "#000" }
import { someColor } from './core-styles/brand/_variables.scss' // #000
```

> **Note:** I tend to include quotes within Sass Maps, but you can omit them.

Comment: That was really helpful. The only answer that works!

Comment: I don't know why, but this doesn't seem to work anymore for some reason :(
https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-night-92rij

Comment: One has to write: `@each $key, $value in $theme-colors { #{$key}: #{$value}; }`

ie. must interpolate variables

Comment: i got stuck trying to `@use 'sass:string'` and then use `string.unquote` but turns out I just had to call `unquote` directly and it worked like this answer!

Comment: Hi, thx for your example.
does anyone know where the keyword ":export {" comes from? i mean from which domain / programming language / build tool is it? 

Greetings, hve a nice day

Comment: Handy little snippet, that is! Worked like a charm for me with a little finagling. I'm on next.js, so I had to create a `colors.module.scss` to prevent exporting from a global file. I didn't need the unquote function, either. Cheers  Ah, and of course TS is complaining `no exported member` from the scss file  Can't have everything, I guess.

Answer (score 27):

Taking a Cue from Bootstrap 4, you could combine a SASS map with a loop like below;

```css
/* Define all colours */
$theme-colours: (
  some-color: #000,
  another-color: #000,
  third-color: #000,
  fourth-color: #000
)

@each $color, $value in $theme-colours {
  :export{
    $color: $value;
  }
}
```

Here's some examples from the [Bootstrap 4 Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/getting-started/theming/)

Comment: I thought about using this but I am not overly keen on using a map to reference all my colours. I will accept this as the answer though as I was going to post up the same because I am fairly confident this is the only way to achieve it...