# Export SASS/SCSS variables to Javascript without exporting them to CSS

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, sass

### Background

Consider the following `_variables.scss` file:

```
/* Define all colours */
$white:    #fff;
$black:    #000;
$grey:     #ccc;
// etc...

// Export the color palette to make it accessible to JS
:export {
    white: $white;
    black: $black;
    grey: $grey;
    // etc...
}
```

The purpose of the above code is to make the SCSS variables available to Javascript by means of importing like so:

```
import variables from 'variables.scss';
```

See a more detailed description [here](https://www.bluematador.com/blog/how-to-share-variables-between-js-and-sass).

### The Problem

Now consider the following template (I have used as Vue.js template as an example but this is relevant to numerous frameworks):

```
<!-- Template here... -->

<style lang="scss" scoped>

    // Import Partials
    @import "~core-styles/brand/_variables.scss";
    @import "~core-styles/brand/_mixins.scss";

    // Styles here...

</style>
```

*In the above example I have used the `scoped` attribute as this demonstrates the worst case scenario for the upcoming problem, but even without `scoped` the problem is still relevant.*

The above SCSS will compile to something along the lines of:

```
[data-v-9a6487c0]:export {
    white: #fff;
    black: #000;
    grey: #ccc;
    // etc...
}
```

In addition, with the `scoped` attribute, this will repeat **every** time `_variables.scss` is imported into a template, and *can* potentially result in additional redundant code. In some cases, for large applications (many components and a large colour palette), this can literally add 000's of lines of completely redundant code.

### My Question

Is there a way to export the SCSS variables to Javascript **without** exporting them to CSS?

### Potential (dirty) Solution

I am ideally trying to avoid a solution of having a separate file named, for example, `_export.scss` where its purpose is simply to export all SCSS variables to JS, but it is excluded from all CSS builds...

Just to expand on the above *dirty* solution, this is what I am currently resorting to (in my case, on a standard size website, it has so far saved me ~600 lines of redundant CSS code):

**`_export.scss`**

```
/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | SASS Export
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Define any variables that should be exported to Javascript. This file
 | is excluded from the CSS builds in order to prevent the variables from
 | being exported to CSS.
 |
 */

@import "variables";

:export {

    // Export the color palette to make it accessible to JS
    white: #fff;
    black: #000;
    grey: #ccc;
    // etc...

}
```

Then, in my Javascript instead of importing from `_variables.scss`, I import from `_export.scss` like so:

```
import styles from 'core-styles/brand/_export.scss';
```

And finally, the `export` statement, can now be removed from the `_variables.scss` file, thus preventing the compiled CSS `export` code.

**Note:** The `_export.scss` file **must** be excluded from the SCSS compilation!

Comment: Can anyone point to a way of actually excluding the file containing the exports from compilation? Specifically, when using Vite/Rollup for building. I have tried the `build.optimizeDeps` and `build.rollupOptions.external` options as well as the postcss-exclude-files plugin with the `css.postcss.plugins` option and the filter option of the plugin set to `'**/*.module.*'`. Nothing seems to have any effect.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> **Note:** I have posted this answer because it seems there is no *better* solution, however, if someone subsequently provides a better solution, I will be more than happy to accept it.

It seems that the only real solution to this is to extract the `export` statement out of the `_variables.scss` file and place it into its own `_export.scss` file which will subsequently **not** be included in the SCSS compliation.

This will look something like this:

**_variables.scss** - included in the SCSS compilation

```
/* Define all colours */
$white:    #fff;
$black:    #000;
$grey:     #ccc;
// etc...
```

**_export.scss** - **not** included in the SCSS compilation

```
@import "variables";

:export {

    // Export the color palette to make it accessible to JS
    white: #fff;
    black: #000;
    grey: #ccc;
    // etc...

}
```

And then your `app.scss` (I use `brand.scss`) file will look something like this (note the absence of `@include "export";`):

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "core";
@import "animations";
// etc...
```

Then, `_export.scss` is simply referenced **only** in JavaScript like so (note that `core-styles` is just an alias that I used in my projects):

```
import styles from 'core-styles/brand/_export.scss';
```

Comment: I'm having some difficulties achieving what you have outlined here, would you mind taking a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517117/cannot-export-sass-variables-into-javascript

Comment: If I do this with rollup the styles is an empty string, e.g. "". Any experience with getting this to work with Rollup?

Comment: This wasn't working for me as is, I kept getting an empty object back for the `styles` variable.  After updating `_export.scss` to be `_export.module.scss`, I was then able to get back the variables

Comment: @Stetzon, your comment was the only solution that worked for me as well. I wonder what your webpack.js looks like

Comment: @Stetzon's solution works for Parcel as well

Comment: When I use `:export` in one of my SCSS files, I get an webpack error: "Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token" using sass-loader@13.0.2_sass@1.54.4+webpack@5.74.0 in an Angular / TS app. Any idea what is missing?

Comment: @PeterT. Have you solved your problem? I have the same thing!

Comment: @Murat No, I used a different approach and a workaround without `:export` then.

Comment: How is your workaround I also had to there a workaround like keeping the content in a variable.

Comment: @Stetzon’s comment about needing to use the “.module.scss” extension for exports to work applies to Vite/Rollup builds, too. I found the article https://medium.com/@UReyesMeUp/using-sass-variables-in-your-react-components-e3813a6cc81e that clearly states this as a general requirement for use of style exports in React components – but presumably for other frameworks, too.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this is caused by using `@import` instead of using `@use`.

`@import` is deprecated precisely because it copy-pastes, so multiple imports result in multiple copies of the same contents.

Answer (score 0):

Copy your SCSS vars as CSS vars (--white, --black etc) and then:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('--white')
```

Downside is polluting the document with probably not needed CSS vars.
Upside - you don't need any (convoluted) export/import.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).