# Gatsby Build Breaks SCSS Export Variables

Tags: javascript, sass, material-ui, gatsby

I have a SCSS variables file which has:

```
$brandColorAnchor: #14314e;

:export {
  brandColorHighlight: $brandColorHighlight;
}
```

And then in my JavaScript file I am passing these variables to Material UI, but the variables are seem to be coming in undefined. The build throws an error saying that each color in material UI needs main defined.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles"
import Variables from "../styles/variables.scss"

const Theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: Variables.brandColorHighlight
    }
  }
})

export default Theme
```

This error only happens on gatsby build and not on gatsby develop.

Comment: you already checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57538082/614659

Comment: @Logemann yes, the variables are still undefined when using the scss file extension

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. There is no solution.