# Use CSS-modules variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, global-variables, css-modules

I wonder if there is a way I can share my color variables in css-modules to my js (React) components?

If not, how would you do it? Have two files with color variables?

Thanks!

Comment: In SCSS, you'd do like that https://stackoverflow.com/q/57536228/8186898 probably webpack with some plugin allow you to use the same syntax in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

CSS doesn't have the concept of variables [like Sass does](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables), so I'll assume you're referring to [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties), which a lot of people refer to as "CSS variables".

These custom properties are just that - custom style properties than are set to particular elements and that can be accessed at runtime by JS through [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) + [`getPropertyValue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleDeclaration/getPropertyValue). Here's an example:

```js
const root = document.documentElement;
const div = document.querySelector('div');
const x = document.getElementById('x');

const get = (elt, key) => getComputedStyle(elt).getPropertyValue(key);

console.log(
  get(root, '--foo'), // 'Foo!'
  get(div, '--bar'), // 'Bar!'
  get(x, '--baz'), // 'Baz!'
  get(x, '--foo'), // 'Foo!' because properties cascade down
)
```

```css
:root {
  --foo: 'Foo!';
}
div {
  --bar: 'Bar!';
}
#x {
  --baz: 'Baz!';
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="x"></div>
```

As far as I know, there is no official way to export values from CSS files in a way similar to what you'd do in ESM (eg `export const mainColor = '#ff0000';`).

Sass however supports that, the syntax is [as follow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57536228/8186898) and requires a proper support from the sass processor you're using:

```
// colors.scss
:export {
  main-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```js
import colors from './colors.scss';
console.log(colors['main-color']); // '#ff0000'
```

Comment: Ok, I'm using variables in CSS-modules, like you can se here https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules/blob/master/docs/values-variables.md

And it's these variables/values I'm asking if I can use in JS/(react) somehow :) Maybe I have the wrong terminology or something? I have always called them variables :)