# Using SCSS `:export` causes webpack error: "Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token"

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, sass

I want to use variables defined in SCSS in TypeScript modules in a Angular app.
An quite elegant way seems to use SCSS `:export`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57536228/export-sass-scss-variables-to-javascript-without-exporting-them-to-css) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517117/cannot-export-sass-variables-into-javascript) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523785/exporting-scss-variables-to-js-auto-looping-variables).

But when I use `:export` in one of my SCSS files, I get an webpack error:

```
./src/styles/_export.scss:16:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (16:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/.pnpm/resolve-url-loader@5.0.0/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/.pnpm/sass-loader@13.0.2_sass@1.54.4+webpack@5.74.0/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| 
| 
> :export {
|   dialogWidth: 600px;
|   sidenavWidthExpanded: 280px;

Error: src/app/modules/help/services/help.service.ts:12:29 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@styles/_export.scss' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

Any idea what is missing?
Is there another loader required as the error message suggests?
Is anything outdated?

In fact, I'm not quite sure which tool would process the `:export` as it does not seem to be a SASS feature, but rather [ICSS](https://github.com/css-modules/icss) as pointed out by [PaulCo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61517117/cannot-export-sass-variables-into-javascript#comment121595701_61566685).

Looking at my `pnpm-lock.yaml` it seems that 3 different versions of the `css-loader` are used (and all depend on some version of icss-utils), no idea which one of those is in fact used to build:

```
  /css-loader/3.6.0_webpack@4.46.0:
    resolution: {integrity: sha512-M5lSukoWi1If8dhQAUCvj4H8vUt3vOnwbQBH9DdTm/s4Ym2B/3dPMtYZeJmq7Q3S3Pa+I94DcZ7pc9bP14cWIQ==}
    engines: {node: '>= 8.9.0'}
    peerDependencies:
      webpack: ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0
    dependencies:
      camelcase: 5.3.1
      cssesc: 3.0.0
      icss-utils: 4.1.1
      loader-utils: 1.4.0
      normalize-path: 3.0.0
      postcss: 7.0.39
      postcss-modules-extract-imports: 2.0.0
      postcss-modules-local-by-default: 3.0.3
      postcss-modules-scope: 2.2.0
      postcss-modules-values: 3.0.0
      postcss-value-parser: 4.2.0
      schema-utils: 2.7.1
      semver: 6.3.0
      webpack: 4.46.0

  /css-loader/5.2.7_webpack@5.74.0:
    resolution: {integrity: sha512-Q7mOvpBNBG7YrVGMxRxcBJZFL75o+cH2abNASdibkj/fffYD8qWbInZrD0S9ccI6vZclF3DsHE7njGlLtaHbhg==}
    engines: {node: '>= 10.13.0'}
    peerDependencies:
      webpack: ^4.27.0 || ^5.0.0
    dependencies:
      icss-utils: 5.1.0_postcss@8.4.18
      loader-utils: 2.0.3
      postcss: 8.4.18
      postcss-modules-extract-imports: 3.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-modules-local-by-default: 4.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-modules-scope: 3.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-modules-values: 4.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-value-parser: 4.2.0
      schema-utils: 3.1.1
      semver: 7.3.8
      webpack: 5.74.0

  /css-loader/6.7.1_webpack@5.74.0:
    resolution: {integrity: sha512-yB5CNFa14MbPJcomwNh3wLThtkZgcNyI2bNMRt8iE5Z8Vwl7f8vQXFAzn2HDOJvtDq2NTZBUGMSUNNyrv3/+cw==}
    engines: {node: '>= 12.13.0'}
    peerDependencies:
      webpack: ^5.0.0
    dependencies:
      icss-utils: 5.1.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss: 8.4.18
      postcss-modules-extract-imports: 3.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-modules-local-by-default: 4.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-modules-scope: 3.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-modules-values: 4.0.0_postcss@8.4.18
      postcss-value-parser: 4.2.0
      semver: 7.3.8
      webpack: 5.74.0_esbuild@0.15.5
```